# Cloud Endpoints generating HTTP 404 for special characters passed as named parameter

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I've created very simple endpoint with one HTTP GET method. I'm passing one string as ApiMethod named parameter:

```
@Api (name = "sample_endpoint")
public class SampleEndpoint
{
    public Entity get(@Named("parameter") String parameter)
    {
        return new Entity(parameter);
    }

    public class Entity
    {
        public String parameter = "Validated ok.";
        public Entity(String parameter) { this.parameter = parameter; }
        public String getParameter() { return parameter; }
    }
}
```

When I call URL with parameter containing letters and numbers and some special chars, like `-.`, it works:

```
GET http://localhost:8888/_ah/api/sample_endpoint/v1/entity/passedparam

200 OK
{
 "parameter": "passedparam"
}
```

But when I insert certain special characters into parameter, like `:#/`, I'm getting HTTP 404. Parameter is URL encoded, in example I'm using value `passed:param`

```
GET http://localhost:8888/_ah/api/sample_endpoint/v1/entity/passed%3Aparam

404 Not Found
<html><head><title>Error 404</title></head>
<body><h2>Error 404</h2></body>
</html>
```

Is it bug or feature? Or maybe I'm doing it wrong?

Comment: Did you manged to overcome this? I have the same problem for a week and luck :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been solved as of App Engine SDK 1.8.6

Answer (score 0):

This is now being discussed in [this issue report](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9902). Since the behavior differs in dev and prod, there's definitely a bug here. My suspicion is that what you're trying to do should work in both dev and prod, and there's a bug in the local server.